# Align multiple numbered aligned blocks

Tags: equations, numbering, align

There are many discussions over how to align multiple `align` environments with interspersed texts. However, I want to label multiple `aligned` blocks such that each number will center vertically for each `aligned` blocks and at the same time align across blocks.

Here is a MWE that achieves either at one time. The first part simply uses one giant `align` environment with some `\nonumber` directive. The second one use `equation` to wrap `aligned` but lose alignment info. How should I achieve the best of both worlds?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  % Part I
  \begin{align}
          x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
                z^2 &= 0 \nonumber \\
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1
  \end{align}

  % Part II
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
            z^2 &= 0 \\
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understood you correctly, but seems that `split` environment is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    \begin{split}
      x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
            z^2 &= 0 
    \end{split}             \\
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If anything I learned, it would be that I should read `amsmath`'s documentation rather than googling around!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of correcting for the alignment:

1. If the equations are fairly similar (with some terms missing), you can use `\phantom`.
2. If the equations are very different, use a `\phantom` of the widest element, together with a `math` over`lap`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

% Part I
\begin{align}
        x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
              z^2 &= 0 \nonumber \\
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1
\end{align}

% Part II
\begin{equation}%
  \!\begin{aligned}
    x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
    \phantom{x^2 + y^2 + {}}z^2 &= 0
  \end{aligned}%
\end{equation}

% Part II
\begin{equation}%
  \!\begin{aligned}
    x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
    \phantom{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\mathllap{a^2 - b^2} &= 0
  \end{aligned}%
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

A minor `\!` correction is required in front of `aligned`.

Comment: Thank, you, very helpfull