# Aligned block misaligned with leading extra white space

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I often use `aligned` inside other math environments like `equation, align, gather`, but there's sometimes (always?) an extra white space in front of the `aligned` block, no matter where the `aligned` block is: at the very beginning of a line, or right after an equal sign.

**Here's My Question,** explanation comes after the figure:

> What is the proper way of dealing with this extra white space? If I shouldn't use `aligned` to achieve such layout (shown below), what is the proper alternative?

There seems to be a `split` approach that works in [certain cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348017), but not for me most of the time.

The extra white space seems to have exactly the same width as the negative space \! like shown below:[image]

Please note the misaligned F_H( eta ).

The same `aligned` block appears twice, as Eq.(39) and Eq.(40). The first time (tagged with red) is the whole line being the `aligned` block, whereas Eq.(40) is the effect I want but I had to cheat a bit by inserting a single \! in front of `aligned`.

Here I want to align all the equations at the beginning, but in many other cases the desired alignment point is in the middle.

Now, this tiny extra white space is an issue because

1. I often use `aligned` block right around the `&` inside an `align` environment.
2. In the example shown above, I cannot start `aligned` around the equal sign at the integral but have to do the whole line as an `aligned` because this is the only way to use the `optional [b]` to allow the equation numbering appear at the right place (last line of the `aligned` block).

The posts I found here that address `aligned` issues are not helpful to me, since they are mostly about what I already know very well: the alternating right-left alignment and the additional n-1 `&` one should place in-between the n `&` align points as column divider.

I hope I have stated my question in a comprehensive way, and any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here's the code to generate the equations above:

```
\begin{align}
& F_{XH}(x, \eta) = F_p(x) \cdot p  + F_q(x) \cdot ( 1 - p ) \\
& F_X(x) = \sum_{\eta = -1}^{1} F_{XH}(x, \eta) = p F_p(x) + (1 - p) F_q(x)  \\
& \begin{aligned}[b]% plain version
    F_H(\eta) = \Pr{ H = \eta } &= \int F_{XH}(x, \eta) \dd x \\
    &= p  + ( 1 - p )
    \end{aligned} \quad \text{\color{red}without \textbackslash !} \\
& \!\begin{aligned}[b]% with negative space
    F_H(\eta) = \Pr{ H = \eta } &= \int F_{XH}(x, \eta) \dd x \\
    &= p  + ( 1 - p )
    \end{aligned} \quad \text{\color{blue}with \textbackslash !} \\
& F_{X \mid H}(x\, ;\, \eta_0) = \frac{ p F_p(x) }{ F_X(x) } 
     + \frac{ (1-p) F_q(x) }{ F_X(x) } 
\end{align}
```

Comment: sounds like the situation described here: [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the `aligned` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482)

Comment: is that with the amsmath release of `2016/11/05 ` ????

Comment: @barbarabeeton which reminds me I should post a new answer to that question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- don't eliminate the information that's there now; just add the new information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes sure I'd post a new answer not erase Frank's or yours:-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. Oops I wonder how I didn't find the post you shared or any of the 7 posts linked therein.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin -- it helps if one knows the post is there.  (i have a link squirreled away in [Often referenced questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2419/579) because it does come up fairly regularly.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Whoa, perhaps this should be a default favorite post for any new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an up to date `amsmath` release you get

[image]

To get the output that you show you need to use the compatibility option `[alignedleftspaceyes]`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
%[alignedleftspaceyes]
{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
& F_{XH}(x, \eta) = F_p(x) \cdot p  + F_q(x) \cdot ( 1 - p ) \\
& F_X(x) = \sum_{\eta = -1}^{1} F_{XH}(x, \eta) = p F_p(x) + (1 - p) F_q(x)  \\
& \begin{aligned}[b]% plain version
    F_H(\eta) = \Pr{ H = \eta } &= \int F_{XH}(x, \eta) \dd x \\
    &= p  + ( 1 - p )
    \end{aligned} \quad \text{\color{red}without \textbackslash !} \\
& \!\begin{aligned}[b]% with negative space
    F_H(\eta) = \Pr{ H = \eta } &= \int F_{XH}(x, \eta) \dd x \\
    &= p  + ( 1 - p )
    \end{aligned} \quad \text{\color{blue}with \textbackslash !} \\
& F_{X \mid H}(x\, ;\, \eta_0) = \frac{ p F_p(x) }{ F_X(x) } 
     + \frac{ (1-p) F_q(x) }{ F_X(x) } 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After using for some days the 11/05/2016 release, I noticed that in `align` and `equation` environment it works fine, but in `gather` or `alignat` or `flalign` there's now extra negative white space (\!). I wonder if I'm mistaken or there's something wrong with my TeXShop (even though full updated).

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin sorry I do not know exactly what you mean. Old versions of aligned and gather had a spurious `\,` in their definition so needed `\!` as noted here, new versions should not need it, however this was a surprisingly delicate block of code to change so it is not impossible that a bug was introduced. If you think the new code is doing the wrong thing please open a new question with an example, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I experimented with `gather`, `alignat` and `flalign`, but saw no negative space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the response. Actually I wasn't even sure if there is a new problem cuz it appeared inconsistent to me (sometimes there's the overcorrection of extra negative space, sometimes there isn't). It turns out to be the interaction between how any math environment align symbols from `DeclareMathOperator` or `\newcommand*`. I might post a new question, but this has become rather specific to personal habit now so I might not.

Comment: @egreg I appreciate it. Basically I needed some confirmation to nail down what's going on.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin so are you saying you don't now suspect a bug in the new alignment code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I would not characterize this as a bug. However it's still an inconvenience everytime one wants to align self-defined symbols with `aligned`. One now must manually insert an extra (positive) white space `\,`, whereas previously with the old bug it was automatically there.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin that sounds wrong. Why would you have to add `\,` ?

Comment: there should be no problems with self-defined symbols, the packages such as amssymb or the latex format itself do not use any commands to define symbols that are not available to the user in a document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your interest. See my new post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354778