# Where does this extra negative white space in aligned come from?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, math-operators

An age old issue of the extra leading `\,` white space in `aligned` was solved in the [Nov.5th 2016 release](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353026/119235).

I don't know if the following is related, but ....

> why are the `aligned` blocks misaligned only for self-defined symbols when the ampersand are placed differently within?

Is this something basic that I'm missing?

In the image below, the `align` block tagged (1) has an extra negative white space `\!` compared with the block tagged (4) or just equations (2) and (3).

There's no such problem when the leading symbol is an ordinary letter and not `DeclareMathOperator`, and I have found the same problem with `newcommand*`. See equation (5) ~ (8) or directly use `\mathbb{E}` instead of `\E`.

The situation is the same When the outer environment is `flalign` or `alignat`. (codes not included in this post)

I'd like to know if I must manually insert a `\,` for self-defined symbols. Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{  \mathbb{E}  }

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}[t]
    \E &= L \\
    \E &= \E
\end{aligned} \\
&\E = L \\
&\E = \E \\
&\begin{aligned}[t]
    &\E = L \\
    &\E = \E
\end{aligned} \\    
&\begin{aligned}[t]
    L  &= L \\
    L &= \E
\end{aligned} \\
&L  = L \\
&L = \E \\
&\begin{aligned}[t]
    &L  = L \\
    &L = \E
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should remember that even numbered columns in `align`, `alignat` and `aligned` start with `{}`, so a thin space is inserted if a math operator is at the beginning of the material in such cells. It also happens with `\sin`, for instance. What you see is a thin space in lines 3–6, rather than negative spaces in the other lines.

Comment: having declared `\E` to be an operator the expected use would be like `\sin` with a following argument `\sin\theta` the `mathop` spacing makes sure there is a thin space in `\sin x` (or `\E x`) in none of your examples is `\E` used in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *by design* and has nothing to do with the recent changes in `amsmath`.

In general it is expected that cells in even numbered columns of `align`, `alignat` or `aligned` start with a relation symbol. Therefore, in order to get the spacing right, an implicit empty subformula `{}` is automatically inserted at the start of these cells.

This has a bad consequence when the cell starts with a math operator such as `\sum`, `\sin`, `\log` or whatever is defined by means of `\DeclareMathOperator`.

In fact, the sequence of atoms **Ord** **Op** (here the implicit `{}` and `\E`) causes TeX to insert a thin space (which is wanted in expressions such as `$2\sin x$`). In these cases, remember to add `\!` in order to remove the automatic thin space.

What you see is not a negative space in lines 1–2 and 7–12, but a thin (positive) space in lines 3–6.

Comment: oh this totally makes sense. Yeah the same happens when `\sin` is used in my example, even though there's not an **Ord** coefficient in front. I get it now. Really good to know. No wonder I've had inconsistent experiences in the past. Thanks.